# Single digit clock on Raspberry Pi in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, clock

Brand new here, first question! I was a programer in college, some 15 years ago or so, I picked up a raspberry pi to do some tinkering with and one idea was to try to make a clock like my father made the HARD way back in the 70's, a clock that flashes the time one digit at a time. I have my pi all wired up to an IO chip and that connected to a 7-segment display. I have the display fully working. I used some stock code for the IC chip "MCP23017" and was able to build onto that code by pretty much trial and error and EXCEPTIONALLY rusty programing skills. Never used Python before, but so far hasn't been too hard to figure out.

But now I'm stuck and not sure where to even begin next. I can pull the time into my program and print it to the screen as a complete unit. And I created little functions to display all digits 0-9 but I am at a loss how to take that time and split it into single digits and send those codes. Only way I have been thinking requires many pages of if/elif lines, and that seems very wasteful and dumb, I know it should be easier to be done in under a page of code but I'm at a loss where to begin.

(Python programing in Raspberry Pi) # In case I missed mentioning that

Thanks!
Kevin

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Your question seems to be asking how to perform a particular task (splitting a number into its constituent digits) in Python. Unfortunately, the thrust of your question is buried under a lot of irrelevant context (this is great in conversation, not so great on a  help resource). Please remove the unnecessary context, and include the code that you have, what you would like it to do, and how that differs from what the code actually does.

Comment: I suggest you do some more reading, learn more Python, attempt to solve the problem yourself, THEN ask questions here if you've gotten stuck.

Comment: hey, welcome to the site!  Please share some of your code with us, so we can get an idea of where you are, and where you're getting stuck.  Often enough, in the process of explaining where you are, and where you want to be, you'll find a new way to look at your question, and maybe find the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's an example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1435/590) of using an MCP23017 with the raspberry pi

Assuming your function is called `display_digit`

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%H%M%S")
'105404'
>>> for d in time.strftime("%H%M%S"):
...     display_digit(int(d))
...
```

Comment: Thank you gnibbler! That is EXACTLY what I needed. With some more trial and error messing around and your code snippet right there it is working PERFECTLY!